# Multiple barcode generater in zend barcode in codiegniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am creating library with barcode i have a list of books with accession numbers when i click to call controller its showing one barcode looping is not working kindly help

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->set_barcode();
    }

    private function set_barcode()
    {
            //load library
            $this->load->library('zend');
            //load in folder Zend
            $this->zend->load('Zend/Barcode');
            //generate barcode
        //  Zend_Barcode::render('code128', 'image', array('text'=>$code), array());

        $barcodeOptions[] = array('text' => 19090);
        $barcodeOptions[] = array('text' => 19091);

        // No required options
        $rendererOptions = array();

        for($i=0; $i<=1; $i++){

        return  Zend_Barcode::factory(
                            'code39', 'image', $barcodeOptions[$i], $rendererOptions
          )->render();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do multiple returns, the first one will end the function. Build an array and return it instead :

```
$arrayReturn = array();
for($i=0; $i<=1; $i++)
{
    $bar_code = Zend_Barcode::factory(
                            'code39', 'image', $barcodeOptions[$i], $rendererOptions
          )->render();

        array_push($arrayReturn, $bar_code);  

}
return $arrayReturn;
```

Of course, you will have to adapt the rest of your code.

Comment: Thanx for your suggestion but its not working giving same result

Comment: Then remove `->render()` and do that later on your code